# Linq, `Group By` Date, Month

Tags: linq

I'm struggling with a LINQ Group By question.
I have the following data model:

```
public sealed class Class
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; init; } = null!;
}

public sealed class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public ulong FriendCount { get; set; }

    public ulong ScoreCount { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to build a query, which returns me, for a single class, of collection of 12 elements (one for each month in the last 12 months), which shows me the sum of the "FriendCount" and "ScoreCount" of all persons in that month.

So, here's what I would like to achieve:

```
[
    { date: 01/01/2021, friendCount: 0, scoreCount: 50 },
    { date: 01/02/2021, friendCount: 15, scoreCount: 50 },
    ...
]
```

Is something possible with a LINQ (Group By) expression?

Here's what I achieve to filter the data, based on the date time.

```
    public async Task<Class?> GetData(int id)
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = this.dateTimeProvider.Now;
        DateTime startDateTime = currentDateTime.RemoveMonths(12);

        School? result = await this.context.Class.Include(static class => class.Persons)
                                        .Where(class => class.Id == id)
                                        .Select(
                                             class => new Class
                                             {
                                                 Id = class.Id,
                                                 Persons = class.Persons
.Where(person => person.RegistrationDate >= startDateTime && person.RegistrationDate <= currentDateTime)

// Here I believe something like a group by clausule should be added.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how your desired output will fit into your `Class`/`School` classes, so I'll provide an answer that only addresses the `Person` objects. Hopefully you'll find useful.

For the `.GroupBy()` operation, you can create a new `DateTime` using the `Year` and `Month` values for the specific `Person`'s `RegistrationDate` and use that as each grouping's `Key`.

I will assume that your output class may look as follows:

```csharp
public class MonthlyStats
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ulong FriendCount { get; set; }
    public ulong ScoreCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the grouping and selection could be done as follows:

```csharp
Person[] persons = { ... };

MonthlyStats[] monthlyStats = persons
    .GroupBy(p => new DateTime(p.RegistrationDate.Year, p.RegistrationDate.Month, 1),
        ( firstDayOfMonth, personsInMonth ) => new MonthlyStats
            {
                Date = firstDayOfMonth,
                FriendCount = (ulong)personsInMonth.Sum(p => (decimal)p.FriendCount),
                ScoreCount = (ulong)personsInMonth.Sum(p => (decimal)p.ScoreCount)
            })
    .OrderBy(stat => stat.Date)
    .ToArray();
```

If `persons` is defined as follows:

```csharp
Person[] persons =
{
    new(1, "A", new DateTime(2022, 1, 4), 9, 23),
    new(2, "B", new DateTime(2021, 4, 8), 7, 29),
    new(3, "C", new DateTime(2021, 9, 11), 4, 13),
    new(4, "D", new DateTime(2021, 11, 1), 10, 14),
    new(5, "E", new DateTime(2021, 4, 17), 12, 17),
    new(6, "F", new DateTime(2022, 1, 27), 5, 11),
    new(7, "G", new DateTime(2021, 9, 2), 13, 31),
};
```

, the groupings will be the following:

```csharp
01.01.2022
    (1, "A",  DateTime(2022, 1, 4), 9, 23)
    (6, "F",  DateTime(2022, 1, 27), 5, 11)
01.04.2021
    (2, "B",  DateTime(2021, 4, 8), 7, 29)
    (5, "E",  DateTime(2021, 4, 17), 12, 17)
01.09.2021
    (3, "C",  DateTime(2021, 9, 11), 4, 13)
    (7, "G",  DateTime(2021, 9, 2), 13, 31)
01.11.2021
    (4, "D",  DateTime(2021, 11, 1), 10, 14)
```

and the resulting `MonthlyStats` objects will be:

> Date                FC      SC
> ---------------------------
> 01/04/2021      19      46
> 01/09/2021      17      44
> 01/11/2021      10      14
> 01/01/2022      14      34

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pHwjx5).

---

##### Update -- always return 12 months

To always generate a collection that covers each whole month of the previous year span, you could first generate the collection of "month dates", and then take advantage of [`Enumerable.GroupJoin()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupjoin-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-2))-system-func((-0-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-3)))):

```csharp
var startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - 1, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);

DateTime[] firstDayOfMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
    .Select(i => new DateTime(startDate.AddMonths(i).Ticks))
    .ToArray();

MonthlyStats[] monthlyStats = firstDayOfMonths
    .GroupJoin(persons,
        date => date,
        person => new DateTime(person.RegistrationDate.Year, person.RegistrationDate.Month, 1),
        ( firstDayOfMonth, personsInMonth ) => new MonthlyStats
            {
                Date = firstDayOfMonth,
                FriendCount = (ulong)personsInMonth.Sum(p => (decimal)p.FriendCount),
                ScoreCount = (ulong)personsInMonth.Sum(p => (decimal)p.ScoreCount)
            })
    .ToArray();
```

Using the same `persons` input, the output will now look as follows:

> 01/04/2021      |      19      |      46
> 01/05/2021      |        0      |        0
> 01/06/2021      |        0      |        0
> 01/07/2021      |        0      |        0
> 01/08/2021      |        0      |        0
> 01/09/2021      |      17      |      44
> 01/10/2021      |        0      |        0
> 01/11/2021      |      10      |      14
> 01/12/2021      |        0      |        0
> 01/01/2022      |      14      |      34
> 01/02/2022      |        0      |        0
> 01/03/2022      |        0      |        0

(You may need to adjust the month part in the generation of `startDate`, or the start value in `Enumerable.Range()` to e.g. include the current month, if that is what you rather prefer to have.)

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VetrUh).

Comment: Seems quite what I need so thanks for that, but I have 2 questions. First of all, why in the `Sum` operator does I need to cast my numbers to a decimal and second, is there always return a collection of 12 elements (so 1 for each month), even if there's no data in that month? If I only have the month January and February, there will only be 2 elements in the collection.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted but it would be great if you could still provide an answer to the above question :-)

Comment: (1) [`Enumerable.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0) has no overload that takes an `IEnumerable<ulong>()`, which is why we need a cast. (The cast does not necessarily need to be to `decimal`, though.) (2) With this approach, you will only get data for months that are present in the `Person` collection. Sorry I missed that part of your requirements. I'll provide an example of how to achieve output for all 12 months.

Comment: @Complexity I have added an update below my original answer, hope it fits your needs. :)